# Issue with Specific Nested If Statement in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2010, iif

I created a nested iif statement in 2010 Access and for the most part it works.  However there is once line that will not populate correctly:

```
SELECT
    IIf([qryMARate]![Commissionable],
      IIf([qryMARate]![Year]="2013",
         IIf([Forms]![frmMARate]![chkTrueUp],
            [qryMARate]![AGENTInitial],
            [qryMARate]![AGENTRenewal]),
         IIf([Forms]![frmMARate]![chkTrueUp],
            IIf([qryMARate]![ProRated],
               [qryMARate]![AGENTInitial]*([Forms]![frmMARate]![cboMonth]/12),
               [qryMARate]![AGENTInitial]), <--- This line will not populate
            [qryMARate]![AGENTRenewal]*([Forms]![frmMARate]![cboMonth]/12))),
      Null)
AS AGENTRate FROM qryMARate;
```

The goal of this statement is to pick out if there should be a commission amount and then to either display the commission normally or pro-rate it based upon the month the commission was earned.
Everything else in the statement does as it's supposed to but that one line.  It does not matter what is put in that line it will not populate.

Easiest answer ever, IIf statement was not recognizing the Y and N as possible T/F response, updated Prorated IIF statement to:

```
IIf([qryMARate]![ProRated] = "Yes",
```

Comment: Do you mean whatever the data is it is always executing the line [qryMARate]![AGENTInitial]*([Forms]![frmMARate]![cboMonth]/12) instead of [qryMARate]![AGENTInitial]? What is the data type of the field [qryMARate]![ProRated]?

Comment: @Swagata [qryMARate]![ProRated] is a Text Field with either a Y or N. And yes is if the statement gets to the ProRated check it only outputs [qryMARate]![AGENTInitial]*([Forms]![frmMARate]![cboMonth]/12) instead of [qryMARate]![AGENTInitial].

Comment: That is the problem. You know the Y is yes and N is No but for the system it is just a text field with value Y/N. To get this working, you either need to change the datatype of [qryMARate]![ProRated] to a Yes/No field or use a check = "Y". See updated query below.

Comment: Ah...just noticed you have already figured that out and updated your question :)

Answer (score 0):

See comment above

```
SELECT
IIf([qryMARate]![Commissionable],
  IIf([qryMARate]![Year]="2013",
     IIf([Forms]![frmMARate]![chkTrueUp],
        [qryMARate]![AGENTInitial],
        [qryMARate]![AGENTRenewal]),
     IIf([Forms]![frmMARate]![chkTrueUp],
        IIf([qryMARate]![ProRated] = "Y",
           [qryMARate]![AGENTInitial]*([Forms]![frmMARate]![cboMonth]/12),
           [qryMARate]![AGENTInitial]), <--- This line will not populate
        [qryMARate]![AGENTRenewal]*([Forms]![frmMARate]![cboMonth]/12))),
  Null)
AS AGENTRate FROM qryMARate;
```